# How to write a Junit test case for arraylist (retrieving data by location)??. Please prefer the below code

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

This is the complete code . And I need to write a Test case. Please help me out writing the Test Case, i am a beginner and very new to Junit.

```
public class Register1 {

    String name;
    String location;
    int id;
    int salary;

    public Register1(String name, String location, int id, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.id = id;
        this.salary = salary;

    }

}


import java.util.*;

public class Employee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Register1> Emp = new ArrayList<Register1>();
        Emp.add(new Register1("Jack", "London", 101, 800));
        Emp.add(new Register1("Mike", "UK", 100, 60000));
        Emp.add(new Register1("Andrew", "China", 103, 2000));
        Emp.add(new Register1("Michel", "Korea", 106, 300000));
        Emp.add(new Register1("Donald", "London", 102, 90000));

        List<Register1> reg = new ArrayList<Register1>();
        String input = "London";
        for (Register1 adrs : Emp) {
            if (adrs.location.equals(input)) {
                reg.add(adrs);

            }
        }

        for (Register1 adrs : reg) {
            System.out.println("Employee from London:" + adrs.salary + " "
                    + adrs.location + " " + adrs.id + " " + adrs.name);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Employee from London:800 London 101 Jack

Employee from London:90000 London 102 Donald

Comment: What is your question, specifically?

Comment: What are you trying to test for?

Comment: @Mureinik what u edited?Is this clear to U what his question is

Comment: Typically you will be unit testing a method which accepts inputs and generates an output.  Your `main` method above does not use its inputs and generates no output.  Please review documentation for JUnit or TestNG and then post a question.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians I fixed the code indentation and applied the [tag:java] tag to get proper syntax highlighting. It's an obvious edit to make the question easier to read, regardless of any clarifications OP may want to offer.

Comment: i am very new to Junit, Here i am trying to write a Test Case, which should check whether the Actual output match with the Expected output

Comment: suppose if the actual output is Jack London 101 800

Donald London 102 90000, then Expected output should be ..Jack London 101 800

Donald London 102 90000

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd extract the "logic" part of your program to a separate method:

```
public static List<Register1> filtrerByLocation (List<Register1> emp, String location) {
     List<Register1> reg = new ArrayList<Register1>();

     // A for loop would be nicer, IMHO, but keeping OP's style
     Iterator<Register1> itr = emp.iterator(); 
     while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Register1 res = (Register1) itr.next();
        if (res.location.equals("London")) {
            reg.add(res);
        }
     }
}
```

Now, you could easily write a test suite for it. To take the example in the given `main`:

```
@Test
public void testFiler() {
    List<Register1> emp = new ArrayList<Register1>();
    emp.add(new Register1("Jack", "London", 101, 800));
    emp.add(new Register1("Mike", "UK", 100, 60000));
    emp.add(new Register1("Andrew", "China", 103, 2000));
    emp.add(new Register1("Michel", "Korea", 106, 300000));
    emp.add(new Register1("Donald", "London", 102, 90000));

    List<Register1> res = filterByLocation(emp, "London");

    assertEquals (2, res.size());
    assertEquals ("Jack", res.get(0).getName());
    assertEquals ("Donald", res.get(1).getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik,This seems to be better way.